# Migrating from ant to maven

Tags: java, maven, ant, velocity

I have migrated my project from ant to Maven using velocity frame work but I am getting following error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet /Labman threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.text.StrLookup
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    at org.apache.turbine.services.BaseServiceBroker.<init>(BaseServiceBroker.java:93)
    at org.apache.turbine.services.TurbineServices.<init>(TurbineServices.java:164)
    at org.apache.turbine.services.TurbineServices.<clinit>(TurbineServices.java:147)
    at org.apache.turbine.Turbine.<init>(Turbine.java:170)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:379)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Did you add all the jars ?

Comment: Yes i have added  all of them

Comment: i tried adding following jar apache-commons-lang

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says :

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org/apache/commons/lang/text/StrLookup

That means, that apache **commons-lang** is missing in your dependencies:

So you have to add the following to your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>  
</dependency>
```

In addition is to say, if you are using **commons-lang3** but that has an other package name **org/apache/commons/lang3**.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing this in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
<version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Just add it under the tag `<dependencies>` and it should work.

Comment: <dependency>
 <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
 <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
 <version>2.2</version>
</dependency> i have added this

Comment: Did you run a maven install? Also, consider to try upgrading the version to 2.6.

Comment: Try running a maven clean and also clean both your project and your server.